# How to install ros on windows?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I am currently running windows 7 and using a virtual machine running ubuntu 12.04 to interact with my hardware via ROS.  However, my boss says that he wants me to using ROS on windows (so please don't just respond with "don't use ros on windows," I know it only has expirimental support but I have to try).

Right now I am trying to install ROS on my computer but cannot for the life of me figure out how (it is apparently a lot harder than installing it on linux).  If possible, I would like to install ros hydro on my windows 7 operating system, and be able to write and run C++ nodes using microsoft visual C++ (which I already have installed).  Does anyone know how I would go about doing this?

Thanks,

Randy

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/181930/how-to-install-ros-on-windows?/) by [mysteriousmonkey29](https://answers.ros.org/users/9531/mysteriousmonkey29/) on ROS Answers with karma: 170 on 2014-07-01

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mysteriousmonkey29](https://answers.ros.org/users/9531/mysteriousmonkey29/) on 2014-07-01**:
To clarify, I'm trying to follow this installation page:
http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Installation/Windows, but am getting stuck on the Msvc SDK installation link:
http://wiki.ros.org/win_ros/hydro/Msvc%20SDK, because I don't know whether or not I have to install the python stuff if I'm not gonna use it, and I also don't know how to actually install the sdk-hydro folder after downloading it.

**Comment by [mysteriousmonkey29](https://answers.ros.org/users/9531/mysteriousmonkey29/) on 2014-07-02**:
Ok, that seems to have done the trick, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need python. The command line tools, RQT and parts of the build system are all written in python.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-07-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0